SOLUCION PARA EXTENSIÓN ERROR LENS EN VISUAL STUDIO CODE
No funciona la extensión de error lens en visual estudio code con archivos .dart
Busqué información como tal pero no hay ninguna explícitamente sobre lo de mi error
mi archivo .json
  "[python]": {
    "editor.formatOnType": true
  },
  "tabnine.experimentalAutoImports": true,
  "terminal.integrated.automationProfile.windows": null,
  "editor.cursorBlinking": "expand",
  "settingsSync.ignoredExtensions": [],
  "settingsSync.ignoredSettings": [],
  "json.schemas": [
  
  ],
  "editor.indentSize": "tabSize",
  "dart.flutterSdkPath": "C:\\flutter",
  "dart.sdkPath": "C:\\flutter\\bin\\cache\\dart-sdk", // Nueva Línea Agregada
  "terminal.integrated.defaultProfile.windows": "Windows PowerShell",
  "terminal.integrated.profiles.windows": {
    "PowerShell": {
      "source": "PowerShell",
      "icon": "terminal-powershell"
    },
    "Command Prompt": {
      "path": [
        "${env:windir}\\Sysnative\\cmd.exe",
        "${env:windir}\\System32\\cmd.exe"
      ],
      "args": [],
      "icon": "terminal-cmd"
    },
    "Git Bash": {
      "source": "Git Bash"
    },
    "Windows PowerShell": {
      "path": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe"
    }
  },
  "liveServer.settings.donotShowInfoMsg": true,
  "[css]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode"
  },
  "dart.debugExternalPackageLibraries": true, // Nueva Línea Agregada
  "dart.debugSdkLibraries": false,
  "launch": {
    "configurations": [],
    "compounds": []
  },
  "errorLens.replace": [],
  "workbench.iconTheme": "material-icon-theme",
  "editor.guides.bracketPairs": true,
  "errorLens.messageEnabled": true,
  "errorLens.enabled": true,
  "[dart]": {
    "editor.tabSize": 2,
    "editor.insertSpaces": true,
    "editor.detectIndentation": false,
    "editor.suggest.insertMode": "replace",
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Dart-Code.dart-code",
    "editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed"
  },
  "errorLens.borderRadius": "3px",
  "workbench.colorTheme": "Shades of Purple (Super Dark)",
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "files.autoSave": "afterDelay",
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "editor.minimap.enabled": false,
  "explorer.compactFolders": false,
  "terminal.integrated.cursorWidth": 2,
  "terminal.integrated.cursorStyle": "line",
  "terminal.integrated.cursorStyleInactive": "line",
  "terminal.integrated.cursorBlinking": true
}

por dar un ejemplo
          CustomButton( icon: Icons.refresh_rounded ),     
          const SizedBox( height: 10 ),
        ]...

Aquí termina con una coma(,), pero yo le puse accidentalmente tres puntos(...) solo para identificar si está funcionando o no error lens, y no me dice nada.
Ya desinstale y volví a instalar la extensión y no funciona. Probé con archivos de js, python, html. CSS y si funcionan, me da todo correctamente de error lens.

Por lo que veo, la extensión error lens lo único que hace es modificar la manera en que se presentan los errores... no incluye un motor de dart, es decir, no sabe si lo que estás escribiendo es válido o no en tus archivos. Tendrás que bajarte una extensión que permita trabajar con ese lenguaje. De dónde sacaste la idea de que error lens lo hace? Su propia descripción lo dice: "ErrorLens turbo-charges language diagnostic features by making diagnostics stand out more prominently, highlighting the entire line wherever a diagnostic is generated by the language and also prints the message inline"
